# Simular outro ambiente ao utilizar o comando `composer update`

Tags: linux, composer, symfony

Possuo um projeto `Symfony2` com dependências geridas pelo `composer`, com seus respectivos arquivos `composer.json` e `composer.lock` sincronizados entre minha máquina local e o servidor de produção através do `git`.

É sabido que ao rodar o comando `composer update`, algumas verificações das configurações da máquina são feitas antes que as versões de dependências sejam escolhidas, já que em alguns casos existem versões diferentes de um mesmo pacote compatíveis com ambientes diferentes.

Um exemplo de pacote com várias versões é o `symfony/icu`, responsável pela internacionalização do `Symfony2`. A versão escolhida pelo `composer` para esse pacote difere entre 1.0.0 e 1.2.0 dependendo da existência ou ausência da biblioteca `lib-icu` na máquina.

### Caso 1 - Rodar `composer update` na máquina local

Quando rodo `composer update` em minha  **máquina local**, que possui a biblioteca de internacionalização `lib-icu`, é criado um arquivo `composer.lock` que referencia a versão v.1.2.0 do pacote `symfony/icu`.

**Problema:** o servidor de produção não possui a biblioteca lib-icu, então quando eu executo `composer install` a partir do `composer.lock` gerado anteriormente é retornado um erro referente à ausência dessa biblioteca.

### Caso 2 - Rodar `composer update` no servidor de produção

Se, por outro lado, eu executo o `composer update` no meu **servidor de produção**, a dependência automaticamente escolhida do `symfony/icu` é a versão v1.0.0 (que funciona sem o `lib-icu`). Nessa situação, ao executar `composer install` tudo funciona certinho, tanto no servidor de produção quanto em minha máquina local.

### Como simular o ambiente do servidor de produção?

Minha pergunta é: existe alguma maneira de eu executar o `composer update` na minha máquina local forçando que o composer utilize a versão v1.0.0 do pacote `symfony/icu`, em vez de utilizar a versão v1.2.0 baseada na configuração da minha máquina? Isto é, quero executar o `composer update` na minha máquina local, e obter o mesmo resultado que eu obteria se executasse no servidor remoto, como se em minha máquina local não existisse a biblioteca `lib-icu`.

Meu composer.json

```json
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/",
            "Application": "app/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.7",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.4",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.1.3",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Então, o detalhe é que o pacote em questão não tá explícito no meu composer.json. Vou postar ele na pergunta.

Comment: Acredito que o `symfony/icu` seja uma dependência do próprio `symfony/symfony`, então não sei como exigir uma versão específica para este caso.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Eu tentaria incluir esse pacote explicitamente, passando a versão desejada. Capaz que isso tenha prioridade sobre a cadeia de dependências que o composer está usando.

Comment: Hmmm, boa ideia! Vou testar, e aviso aqui se funcionar. Talvez o `symfony/symfony` continue "pedindo" pela versão 1.2.0 da dependência, aí vamos ver como o composer vai resolver isso. Bem, valeu! Vou testar aqui.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sugestão simples e eficaz! Simplesmente adicionei "symfony/icu": "v1.0.0" dentro do bloco "require" do composer.json e meu problema foi resolvido. Escreva isso como resposta que eu marco como aceita.

Comment: @rodrigorigotti Por que a troca da tag? A outra tem wiki, e segue os pardos que definimos: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-arvore, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443/precisamos-de-padronizacao-para-tags-com-mais-de-uma-palavra

Comment: @bfavaretto porque o certo é "symfony", e não "symphony". o ideal é que troquemos as tags da wiki também, porque as pessoas procurarão pelo nome certo, concorda?

Comment: @rodrigorigotti Ok, eu não tinha reparado no erro de grafia. Neste caso o hífen antes do 2 fica ou não? É tanto número de versão quanto parte do nome do produto... Dê uma olhada nas discussões do meta que linkei.

Comment: @bfavaretto é verdade, bem notado. eu havia deixado `symfony2` porque é uma grafia bem comum para o framework, então agora fiquei na dúvida. por outro lado, vou alterar a tag para ficar dentro do padrão do Stack Overflow :) valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tentaria incluir esse pacote explicitamente, passando a versão desejada. É bem possível que isso tenha prioridade sobre a cadeia de dependências que o composer está usando. Acredito que quem pede o `symfony/icu` deve estar pedindo uma versão mínima, usando um coringa (`*`) no número da versão, ou especificando `>= X`.

Portanto, inclua na sua chave `require`:

```
"symfony/icu": "1.0.0" // ou 1.0.*
```